# How can I edit posts in Google Talk like I can do in Skype?

Tags: google-talk

Is there an extension or plugin or something that will allow Google Talk to edit posts like Skype does?

This is, in Skype, one can edit the last line that was immediately posted by right-clicking over it and choosing edit in the pop-up menu, or simply by using `s/foo/bar/`. Google Talk doesn't seem to have that implemented, is there any tool or browser extension that implements it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do this, but I don't have an authoritative reference.

Comment: It's in the XMPP not in the client.

Comment: Skype only allows for edition of the last chat message, which I find very useful. I wonder if XMPP is planning on including such edit capabilities in the future.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is not possible in Google Talk or GMail integrated chat at all. And also it all depends on their cannot be any third-party extension or tool to implement it.

It all depends on the service. It is possible in Skype because Skype allows it. Different services take these things differently. For example, here in SE, we can edit a comment but only within 5 minutes of posting it. You can edit your questions and answers any number of times but then there is an edit history created.

What you are asking for is also impossible in Facebook Chat, Yahoo Messenger. It's like you have sent a message once and that's all it's sent for ever. One thing you can try is chatting "Off the Record" in Google Talk.

Comment: This is not true. You can edit any of you previous messages in Skype and for that you need to right click on that message and select edit submenu. Some technical documentation can be found at the following link and you will understand why editing of sent messages is not possible in [XMPP based clients](http://superuser.com/questions/463112/can-xmpp-jabber-support-editing-of-messages-and-offline-message-like-in-skype)